# Jest Unit Test for React Hooks component with act() error

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-state

I have a problem here that's stumping me, and I don't know how to go about fixing this. I have a very simple React Hooks functional component that uses the `useState` hook, but I am having an issue with writing a test case for it (*in Jest*), with `@testing-library/react`.

Here is the meat of the component:

```
// MyComponent.jsx

import InputComponent from '/some/folder/InputComponent';

...

export function MyComponent() {

  const [randomStateVariable, setRandomStateVariable] = useState('');

  ...

  const handleChange = value => setRandomStateVariable(value);

  ...

  return (
    <InputComponent
      handleChange={handleChange}
      input={{
        value: randomStateVariable || ''
      }}
    />
  );

}
```

And then for my unit test file, I am doing the following:

```
// MyComponent.test.js

import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

...

import MyComponent from 'MyComponent';

...

it('runs handleChange', () => {
  
  const props = {
    actions: {
      someAction: jest.fn()
    },
    input: 'some input value'
  };
  
  ...

  const component = renderer.create(<MyComponent {...props} />);
  const inputSelect = component.root.findByType(InputComponent).props;

  inputSelect.handleChange(props.input);

  expect(props.actions.someAction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(props.input);

});
```

Now, the tests are all passing (*I am using `@testing-library/react` in other test cases in the file*), but I am getting the following error when running the test suite:

```
When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
```

I am not sure how to go about correcting this. I don't have the `@testing-library/react-hooks` package installed, and I am unsure of where I should be importing `act` from. Should I be using the `react-test-renderer` for this, and import `act` from that package, or should I be importing it from `@testing-library/react`?

I don't know how to write a test case, or modify the existing test case, in using `act`, to get rid of the console error. Is there anyone that can assist, or point me in the right direction for something like this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Where did you call `someAction` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TestRenderer.act()](https://zh-hans.reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html#testrendereract) is same with [act()](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#act) of `react-dom/test-utils` module. So you just need to import it from `react-test-renderer` package. `@testing-library/react` is another react test library, you only need to choose one of the two. It will be confusing to use together, because each test library has its test method and process, which may not be compatible.

`act()`:

> When writing UI tests, tasks like rendering, user events, or data fetching can be considered as “units” of interaction with a user interface. `react-dom/test-utils` provides a helper called `act()` that makes sure all updates related to these “units” have been processed and applied to the DOM before you make any assertions:

`inputSelect.handleChange(props.input)` trigger an updated operation, it should be put in `act()`.

E.g.

`MyComponent.test.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import InputComponent from './InputComponent';

export function MyComponent({ actions, input }) {
  const [randomStateVariable, setRandomStateVariable] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (value) => setRandomStateVariable(value);

  return (
    <InputComponent
      handleChange={handleChange}
      input={{
        value: randomStateVariable || '',
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

`MyComponent.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer, { act } from 'react-test-renderer';
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';
import InputComponent from './InputComponent';

describe('65786455', () => {
  it('runs handleChange', () => {
    const props = {
      actions: {
        someAction: jest.fn(),
      },
      input: 'some input value',
    };

    const component = renderer.create(<MyComponent {...props} />);
    const inputSelect = component.root.findByType(InputComponent).props;
    expect(inputSelect.input.value).toBe('');
    act(() => {
      inputSelect.handleChange(props.input);
    });
    expect(component.root.findByType(InputComponent).props.input.value).toBe('some input value');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/65786455/MyComponent.test.tsx
  65786455
    ✓ runs handleChange (24 ms)

--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files           |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 InputComponent.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 MyComponent.tsx    |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.878 s
```

Comment: Ohhhh, I see!! Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!

Comment: Side note - what do you need to do to get a console readout like you have in the above image (with the table output)?

Comment: @Lushmoney Run `npm t -- --coverage ./MyComponent.test.tsx` command to test a single file with coverage report. `npm t` is a npm script: `npm test: jest`

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a million!!